# What are some good starting places (books, web) for learning about Web Servers and Apache?

Tags: apache

I want to learn more about the Apache server and how to configure it.  While I know how to use integrated software like XAMPP, I need to understand how web servers work and how, in particular, Apache works.

Can you recommend a good place for someone like me to start learning?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You might start with http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/tutorials.html  There are many other books .. you might check Amazon for some of the "beginner" books